# GAE OAuth deploy using different accounts based on project

Tags: google-app-engine, maven, deployment, oauth

So when deploying to GAE with maven using OAuth it creates **.appcfg_oauth2_tokens_java** file in your home directory. This works great if you can deploy all your projects with one account. But what can you do when you wish to use different account for one of projects?

Can this file be project specific?

I don't wish to delete this file every time I want to deploy with different account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can prevent storing cookies with `appcfg.sh --oauth2 --no_cookies`.

For use with maven you can add the following config to your `pom.xml`:

```
<plugin>
     <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
     <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>1.9.9</version>
     <configuration>
         <oauth2>true</oauth2>
         <noCookies>true</noCookies>
     </configuration>
</plugin>
```